# unexpected error "! segmentation violation"

Tags: prolog, sicstus-prolog

Recently , when I try to compile my project , sometimes an unexpected error has appeared ,

error :

```
% Execution aborted
% source_info
| ?- 
! segmentation violation
```

Is there an explanation for what happens!

Comment: Please be more specific. Include information needed to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @repeat just when I Try to  compile my project with(alt+K) , unexpected error has appeared,  after restart my eclipse it's ok, this error is rarely occurred

Comment: When you say "compile" do you actually mean "execute"? Prolog doesn't really compile but rather it's interpreted. So the interpreter would check syntax, then interpret/execute. For an intermittent error like this, it's very tough to tell what the cause might be. It's likely fault of your program if it has deep recursion, possibly causing stack issues that may not be caught until a segmentation fault. I'd start with looking at your recursion. If you were totally convinced, somehow, that it's not your program, then you'd have to reinstall your environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a bug in SICStus Prolog (unless your Prolog code loads your own C code). Reinstalling will most likely not help.

Please send all relevant information (exact SICStus version and OS version) and preferably a way to reproduce the problem, to the SICStus support email address. Also, try it in the latest version, i.e. 4.3.2.

A reproducer that works without using SPIDER would be easiest for us to work with.

(I am one of the SICStus developers)

Comment: firstly,  I am very appreciated for your response,
I have The latest version 4.3.2 but this problem is not often appear, but when I restart Eclipse and execute the project in first time

Comment: actually, it is a beginner project but how can I send it to you

Comment: Mail me a download link via sicstus-support@sics.se, with information on what you did. If you have no download link you can contact me there anyway so we can arrange something.

Comment: Ok and Thank you very much